# Calculate inputs from form in Javascript and display in message field

Tags: javascript, forms

1. I am trying to calculate a score and prompt one of 3 messages depending on the score. However, seems like I can't push the message to lower part of the form. Mind providing some guidance? THANKS!

   Diabetes Risk Assessment Tool

   ## The Diabetes Risk Assessment Tool

   *Please complete the form. Choose an option for each question* ***

   ```
   <legend>Questions</legend>

   <!-- How old are you?-->
     <span>
     <label for="age">How old are you? </label>
     <input type="radio" value="0" name="age" id="#0-25" checked><label for="0-25">0-25</label>
     <input type="radio" value="5" name="age" id="#26-40"><label for="26-40">26-40</label>
     <input type="radio" value="8" name="age" id="#41-60"><label for="41-60">41-60</label>
     <input type="radio" value="10" name="age" id="#60+"><label for="60+">60+</label><br>
     </span
   ```

   ```
     <span>
     <label for="bmi">What is your BMI? </label>
     <input type="radio" value="0" name="bmi" id="#0-25" checked><label for="0-25">0-25</label>
     <input type="radio" value="0" name="bmi" id="#26-30"><label for="26-30">26-30</label>
     <input type="radio" value="9" name="bmi" id="#31-35"><label for="31-35">31-35</label>
     <input type="radio" value="10" name="bmi" id="#35+"><label for="35+">35+</label><br>
     </span>
   ```

   Does anybody in your family have diabetes? 
         No.
         Grandparent
         Sibling
         Parent

      
         How would you describe your diet? 
         Low-sugar
         Normal sugar
         Quite high sugar
         High sugar

   ```
     </fieldset>

     <div id="displaymessage"></div>

     </form>
   ```

   ```js
       //create variable radios with the radio button values
       var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input")


       function calculateTotal(){

           var total = 0;

           for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {


   ----------


               if (radios[i].type == 'radio' && radios[i].checked) {
                   total += Number(radios[i].value);
               }
           }
               return total;
       }



       //Display message Function


       function displaymessage () {

         //create empty variable
         var message = 0

         //run function calculate total and store in score var
         score = calculateTotal()

         //Depending on your score, you get a message

         if (score < 15) {
           message = "Your results show that you currently have a low risk of developing diabetes"
         }
         else if (score > 25) {
           message = "Your results show that you currently have a high risk of developing diabetes. Your main risk factors are your" + risk1 + "and your" +  risk2 + "We advise that you contact the Health Authority to discuss your risk factors as soon as you can. Your main risk are X and Y."
         }
         else {
           message = "Your results show that you currently have a medium risk of developing diabetes"
         }

         //push result to element display message on HTML
         document.getElementById('displaymessage').innerHTML = message;

       }

       document.getElementById("displaymessage").submit()
   ```

   ```css
       body {
       font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
       }

       .sectionheading {
       color: #ff0000;
       }

       #pageheading{
       font-style: italic;
       }


       label {
         margin-left: 10px;
       }


       .radio-buttons input[type="radio"] {
         width: 10px;
       }

       .radio-buttons label {
         display: inline;
         margin-left: 10px;
         }
   ```

   ```html
       <!doctype html>
       <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Diabetes Risk Assessment Tool</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examplestyles.css">
          <script src="calculate.js"></script>

       </head>

       <h1>The Diabetes Risk Assessment Tool</h1>

       <div class ="radio-inline">

       <form id="assessment">

         <p><i>Please complete the form. Choose an option for each question </i><em>*</em></p>
         <fieldset>

           <legend>Questions</legend>

           <!-- How old are you?-->
             <span>
             <label for="age">How old are you? </label>
             <input type="radio" value="0" name="age" id="#0-25" checked><label for="0-25">0-25</label>
             <input type="radio" value="5" name="age" id="#26-40"><label for="26-40">26-40</label>
             <input type="radio" value="8" name="age" id="#41-60"><label for="41-60">41-60</label>
             <input type="radio" value="10" name="age" id="#60+"><label for="60+">60+</label><br>
             </span

          <!-- Does anybody in your family have diabetes?  -->

             <span>
             <label for="bmi">What is your BMI? </label>
             <input type="radio" value="0" name="bmi" id="#0-25" checked><label for="0-25">0-25</label>
             <input type="radio" value="0" name="bmi" id="#26-30"><label for="26-30">26-30</label>
             <input type="radio" value="9" name="bmi" id="#31-35"><label for="31-35">31-35</label>
             <input type="radio" value="10" name="bmi" id="#35+"><label for="35+">35+</label><br>
             </span>

          <!-- Does anybody in your family have diabetes?  -->
             <label for="genetics">Does anybody in your family have diabetes? </label>
             <input type="radio" value="0" name="genetics" id="No" checked><label for="no">No.</label>
             <input type="radio" value="7" name="genetics" id="grandparent"><label for="grandparent">Grandparent</label>
             <input type="radio" value="15" name="genetics" id="sibling"><label for="sibling">Sibling</label>
             <input type="radio" value="15" name="genetics" id="parent"><label for="parent">Parent</label><br>

          <!-- How would you describe your diet? -->
             <label for="diet">How would you describe your diet? </label>
             <input type="radio" value="0" name="diet" id="low-sugar" checked><label for="low-sugar">Low-sugar</label>
             <input type="radio" value="0" name="diet" id="normal-sugar"><label for="normal-sugar">Normal sugar</label>
             <input type="radio" value="7" name="diet" id="quite-highs-sugar"><label for="quite-highs-sugar">Quite high sugar</label>
             <input type="radio" value="10" name="diet" id="high-sugar"><label for="high-sugar">High sugar</label><br>

          <!-- Calculate -->
              <p><input type="submit" name = "calculate" value="Calculate" id=calculate onsubmit= "displaymessage()"  </p>

             </fieldset>

             <div id="displaymessage"></div>

             </form>

       </div>


       </body>
       </html>
   ```

Comment: Please update your code it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Your function `displaymessage` function (that can be written in camel case `displayMessage` as in Javascript common notation) is not being called properly. To make sure you call this function whenever the form is being submitted, you have to also make sure that you **capture** the `event` and **prevent** it from refreshing the page as it is by **default** on the `<form>` html element:

```
document.getElementById('assessment').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    displaymessage();
});
```

Also remove this line from your calculate.js file:

```
document.getElementById("displaymessage").submit()
```

and remove onsubmit listener from the input button, it is redundant:

```
 <p><input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate" id="calculate"></p>
```

*making sure that the id has quotes around the value: `id="calculate"`*

Finally, you can get `risk1` and `risk2` values by **storing** the **values** and **names** from all the radio elements and **sorting** them afterwards:

1. **first step**: Initialise your two variables `risk1` and `risk2` at the top of your calculate.js file:

   `var risk1, risk2;`
2. **second step**: edit your `calculateTotal` function to this:

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  var objectArray = []; // initialise empty array
  var total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].type == 'radio' && radios[i].checked) {
      //save the values and names of the radio buttons into an array of objects
     objectArray.push({
      value: Number(radios[i].value), 
      name: radios[i].name
     });
     total += Number(radios[i].value);
    }
  }
  //sorting the array ascendingly 
  objectArray.sort(function(a, b){return a.value - b.value});
  // getting the name property of the last two values of the array that are the highest in value
  risk1 = objectArray[objectArray.length - 1].name;
  risk2 = objectArray[objectArray.length - 2].name;
  return total;
}
```

3. **third step**: make sure you properly display the message:

```js
if (score < 15) {
  message = "Your results show that you currently have a low risk of developing diabetes"
} else if (score > 25) {
  message = "Your results show that you currently have a high risk of developing diabetes. Your main risk factors are your " + risk1 + " and your " +  risk2 + ". We advise that you contact the Health Authority to discuss your risk factors as soon as you can. Your main risk are " + risk1 + " and " + risk2;
} else {
  message = "Your results show that you currently have a medium risk of developing diabetes"
}
```